# C++ SFINAE detect increment operator

Tags: c++, sfinae

I am trying to detect presence of pre-increment operator for both class & primitive types. I tried following:

```
template <typename T>
struct has_pre_increment
{
    template <typename U, typename = decltype(++(std::declval<U>()))>
    static long test(const U&&);
    static char test(...);

    static constexpr bool value = sizeof(test(std::declval<T>())) == sizeof(long);
};

struct C
{
    int operator++();
};

struct D
{

};

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha;
    std::cout << has_pre_increment<int>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << has_pre_increment<C>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << has_pre_increment<D>::value << std::endl;
}
```

Result was correct for classes, however, for `int` it was not able to detect pre increment operator. Do you have any idea why? How is it possible to detect `operator++` for any type?

Comment: `std::declval<U&>()`

Comment: @Columbo right, but why?

Comment: `std::declval` yields an _rvalue_, and the operand for the built-in pre-increment operator [needs to be](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_incdec) a non-const _lvalue_.